# Meteor Iron Router documentation

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Where can I find more information about Meteor Iron Router. I've [this](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#hooks) one already.

Comment: The link you have is enough to understand iron:router . You can ask if you have problem in implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry but in the Guide, they don't show me how a template gets data context (from a cursor, a function or an object - a post by Samuel Schoebel helps me understand). Besides, I wonder the difference between two ways to create a route (Router.map() and Router.route()).

Comment: I take your point, but if you think the documentation on the repo is inadequate, you're probably better off raising an issue on the repo than asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to get data into your template.

First: with a helper-function

```
Template.someTemplate.helpers({
  nameOfHelper: function() {
    return Collection.find();
  }
});
```

Second: with Iron-Router:

```
`Router.route('/path', {
  action: function () {
    this.render('template', {
        data: function () {
            return Collection.findOne('someId');
        }
    });
  }
});`
```